# Unable to retrieve Contacts using Loader Call back methods

Tags: android, android-loader

I am building a simple app wherein I want to retrieve all the Contacts from the phone and display it in a textView. Using the loader CallBack methods for same but I get a blank screen after pressing the Load Button. have also provided the read and write permitions for same. Posting my Code below, Please help.
Thanks in advance

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sumeet.contentproviderdemoyoutube;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    String TAG = "Show";

    private String mColumnProjection[] = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};

    private String mSelectionClause = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + "='Simpi'";
    private String[] mSelectionArguments = new String[]{"Simpi"};
    private String mOrderBy = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load);
        //   ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
//        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
//                mColumnProjection,
//                mSelectionClause,
//                null,
//                null);


    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.load:
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        if (i == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Inside onloader", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnFinish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                stringBuilder.append(cursor.getString(0) + "," + cursor.getString(1) + "," + cursor.getString(2) + "\n");
            }
            textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
        } else {
            textView.setText("No Contacts to display");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onLoader", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.sumeet.contentproviderdemoyoutube.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/load"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sumeet.contentproviderdemoyoutube">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is your sdk version and device model ?

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in your `onLoadFinished()` method and stepped through your code, what did you see happen?

Comment: Hi I am using my Phone to run this application. Lenovo Vibe k5, Android 5.1.1 , API 22

Comment: @CommonsWare I am getting nothing as output in the text view. Not even sure if I am invoking the onLoadFinished() as theirs no output and no errors aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Change the init loader call in `onClick()` to

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this).forceLoad();
```

Also [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) states that

> Blockquote A CursorLoader must be built with the full information for the query to perform, either through the `CursorLoader(Context, Uri, String[], String, String[], String)` or creating an empty instance with `CursorLoader(Context)` and filling in the desired paramters with `setUri(Uri)`, `setSelection(String)`, `setSelectionArgs(String[])`, `setSortOrder(String)`, and `setProjection(String[])`.

Try to provide this information to CursorLoader constructor

Comment: Still the Same.